# Sequence-id in associated expression for dynamic lookup in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping using a dynamic lookup on target table followed by a target table.
The target table has a primary id column that is passed from the lookup column where I have used 'Assoicated Expresion -> Sequence-id'.

Here the primary key id is incremented with every row insert in target table.

Now the current value in lookup cache is 10, but I want it to start the new id from 20.

Is there any way we could increment the Sequence-id to desired value from the cache?

Thanks for the help!